# How to prove $E(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty X_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty EX_n$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

How to prove that if $X_n>0$, then $E(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty X_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty EX_n$?

I think I should use something like monotone convergence theorem, but I really don't know how to apply it. Can anyone be kind enough to give me the answer. I will be very grateful!!

Comment: Please replace each $i=1$ by $n=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is the monotone convergence theorem.

Note that if you write $\mathbb E(\cdot)$ as $\int (\cdot) d\mathbb P $ and also write $\sum_{i=1}^\infty(\cdot)$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n(\cdot)$, you can rewrite your desired statement as

$$\int \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ d\mathbb P = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ d\mathbb P$$

And now we define $S_n:= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ which is again a random variable (why?). Moreover $(S_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is monotone (why?).

Do you now see how to apply the monotone convergence theorem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for [Tonelli's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions).

Comment: I cannot find any double integral.

Comment: Both the expectation and the infinite sum can be expressed as integration with respect to appropriate measures.

Comment: Indeed, but Tonelli states that $\int\int fd\mu d\nu=\int\int fd\nu d\mu$ under suitable conditions. Where is that practicized if it comes to an answer of the question?

Comment: It is starting to become clear to me, now. Sorry. But I think you should elaborate to make things more clear for the OP. It is too late for withdrawing my downvote. If you elaborate then I will compensate with an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Define $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ and $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_{k}$.

Then $S_{n}\uparrow S$ monotonically and Lebesgues [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)
tells us that $\mathbb{E}S_{n}\uparrow\mathbb{E}S$.

Here $\mathbb{E}S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}X_{k}$
so that $\mathbb{E}S_{n}\uparrow\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}X_{k}$

Combination of these facts give: $$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}X_{k}$$